# {} around my string in Python using tkinter

Tags: python, string, tkinter

I use Tkinter, and I wanted to print a more sophisticated text on a button. It consists of strings parts, variables that contain e.a `'MyString'`, and integer Variables. 
What it does when i grid the buttons, is following :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mFKvD.png)

Here is the code for my first button :

```
bouttons_annuler[(mon_compteur_annulations_loc)].config(text = ("Vend", action_corr_numero_ventes_loc, "x", vente_suivie_loc,"a", entry_prix_loc, euros.get(), "\n","Annuler"))
```

and for my second button :

```
bouttons_annuler[(mon_compteur_annulations_loc)].config(text = ("Offre achat", action_corr_numero_achats_loc, "x", achat_suivie_loc, "Annuler"))
```

Where `action_corr_numero_ventes_loc` represents `'Facebook'` ; `vente_suivie_loc` represents `20` (as an integer) ; `entry_prix_loc` represents also `20` (as an integer) ; `euros.get()` represents `euros=StringVar(master=root)
euros.set('€ :')`

Why does this happen, and how can i solve this? i tried to apply the str() function to all of it, but it didn't work (wouldn't really have made sense if it worked)

Comment: `format()` is your friend

Comment: where do I use it? I tried using it around everything, but it gives me an error saying that format() takes at most 2 arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This:

Edit:

```
texts = 'Vend {} x {} a {} {} \n Annuler'.format(action_corr_numero_ventes_loc, vente_suivie_loc, entry_prix_loc, euro)

bouttons_annuler[(mon_compteur_annulations_loc)].config(text =texts)
```

Comment: It still gives me {€ :}

Comment: and gives me this error :
    bouttons_annuler[(mon_compteur_annulations_loc)].config(text = ('Vend %s x %d a %d %s' % action_corr_numero_ventes_loc, vente_suivie_loc, entry_prix_loc, euros.get()))
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string

Comment: I changed `texts` into : `texts = 'Vend {} x {} a {} {} \n Annuler'.format(action_corr_numero_ventes_loc, vente_suivie_loc, entry_prix_loc, euros.get())` (just added the `s.get()` after euro and the `\n`) and it worked! Thank you so much !

Comment: Glad i could help.

Answer (score 1):

You get the curly braces because you are giving tkinter a tuple. The curly braces are the internal tcl interpreter's method of rendering lists.

You should explicitly convert your data to a string to get rid of the curly braces. For example:

```
bouttons_annuler[...].config(text = ' '.join(("Vend", action_corr_numero_ventes_loc, ...)))
```

Of course, you don't have to use `join`. You can format the data however you want. If you give tkinter a tuple or list, though, you're at the mercy of it deciding how to represent your data.

Comment: Did you actually mean reading or rending itself, over at _"...method of rending lists"_ .

Comment: @CoolCloud: I meant "rendering". Thanks for pointing that out.